# How to convert an informal proof to something formal?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, induction

Q: Prove that for a 0-2 non-empty binary tree, num of external nodes=num of internal nodes+1

Here is a proof I came up with while in class a completely diff proof was discussed. Is this correct?

Proof:
$n_e$ = num of external nodes
$n_i$ = num of internal nodes

Induction Hypothesis: For a 0-2 non-empty finite binary tree, $n_e$=$n_i$+1

Proof: By induction on $n_i$

- Base Case: $n_i$ =0 in case of binary tree with 1 vertex. $n_e$=1, so P(0) is true
- Induction Step: For a tree with $n_i$ internal nodes, we have $n_e$=$n_i$+1. Now we add 1 internal node. This can be done only by converting a leaf (ie external node) to an internal node. (Does this require a proof?) In this case, we have $n_i'$=$n_i$+1. And by property of 0-2 btree, we have to add 2 children to this internal node, in this process, $n_e'$=$n_e$-1+2=$n_e$+1. Hence, $n_e'$=$n_e$+1=$n_i$+2=$n_i'$+1, hence proved.

Another of my proofs on the same proposition can be found here.
[How to write formal proofs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4242218/520436)

My prof says I write "too much story/informally" while structuring proofs. But I can't seem to rectify myself. Any help?

Comment: If you don't understand something/ need more explanation, please write here. I will modify my question

Comment: Please ask about one proof/one question in any given post.

Comment: sure @amWhy. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Since the other proof that you have since deleted is pertaining to the same exercise, and your question is not merely "What is wrong with each of these 2 proofs?" but rather, "My professor has critiqued that my proofs contain too much 'fluff'; I require further elucidation; could someone give more concrete pointers, with reference to these two examples perhaps", I feel that it is okay to include both proofs in this question. It might invite a more educational/interesting answer than one that simply corrects or touches up on this proof.

Comment: okay I will then add a new post, with a link to this post.