# How to write formal proofs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

My main concern here is that my prof considers my proofs too informal, would like me to rectify myself. He says my proofs seem sort of like stories, instead of being rigorous. So I need help in improving my proof.

Q: Prove that a $0$-$2$ finite binary tree satisfies the condition: $n_e=n_i+1$

Proof 2: Induction on height of btree, call it $h$

Height of tree is the maximum depth of a leaf from the root.

- Base case: $h=0$, tree with only $1$ vertex, $P(0)$ is true (skipped a step).
- Induction step: This proposition holds for a btree with height $h$. Now consider a btree with height $h+1$. I now remove all external nodes at height $h+1$ (call it $k$) , I claim there will be an even number of such nodes. If not, we can pair the nodes with $2$ children, and have $1$ external node left with no sibling, then the immediate parent of this would have $1$ child, which violates the condition of a $0$-$2$ btree so $k=2l$. So in this process, I also led to the conversion of exactly $l$ of internal nodes to external ones. So summarising the changes, $n_e'=n_e-2l+l$, $n_i'=n_i-l$, Now we know $n_e'=n_i'+1\implies n_e-l=n_i-l+1 \implies n_e=n_i+1$.
  Hence proved.

I have also written another version of the proof, here in this linked post. Please do check it out too.

[How to convert an informal proof to something formal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4241958/520436)

Comment: I see i need to clarify my doubt right? I understand the concern, please don't close this q. I am making edits to clarify my doubt

Comment: Why are you downvoting this question?

Comment: What is wrong with this? If this is correct, why not write in comments that it is so, I will be more than happy to delete this question. If wrong, why not give some suggestions to help me move in the right direction?

Comment: I don’t think all these downvotes are warranted, I’m giving a +1. I suspect they began on your first draft, which had the problem that your question wasn’t really stated in this post, only in the linked one. But it’s not so good manners not to leave a comment then, since your question wasn’t glaringly bad or anything, and clearly effort has been put into it. But votes tend to snowball. I would advise you though to put all your math in mathjax instead of just some of it - it gives a better impression (and is code of conduct I think).

Comment: I’ll try to give an answer tomorrow. I think I’ll make a polished up version of your proof so you can compare and be inspired how to write differently. I don’t think your proof is so bad at all, but I agree with your professor that the writing could be a bit tighter sometimes. One thing I see immediately is that you don’t define $n’_e$ and $n’_i$ before you use them, so the reader has to guess their meaning (though this is not difficult in context, it’s still a problem). Other than that it’s mostly a question of improving your writing style a bit :-)

Comment: I fixed your mathjax, you should take a look at the edit; especially how to do the longer equations

Comment: Milten's comments say it : I don't think , until you edited your question that there was purpose to what you wrote earlier. I didn't downvote and I wouldn't do so now as well. Anyway, this question has been answered and ticked off, so I suppose job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a polished up version of your proof that you can use as inspiration for writing style. I would at least be more than happy with this as a TA. It's always gonna be a balance between "too informal and verbose"/overly formal/just right. For example, I have chosen not to define $T'$ and the set of removed nodes in formal math notation below, but rather in words.

Note in particular that I give a name $T'$ to the transformed tree to make the distinction clearer, and that I make sure to define everything clearly.

---

We prove the claim by induction on the height $h$ of the tree.

Base case, $h=0$: The only tree of height $0$ is the single node, so we have $n_e=1$ and $n_i=0$, which satisfies the claim.

Induction step: Assume that the claim holds for trees of height $h$, and let $T$ be a $0$-$2$ binary tree of height $h+1$ with $n_e$ external and $n_i$ internal nodes. Let $T'$ be the tree obtained by removing all nodes from the bottom level of $T$, i.e. all the nodes at depth $h+1$. Let $n'_e$ and $n'_i$ be the number of external and internal nodes of $T'$. Note that the nodes of depth $h+1$ are necessarily external in $T$, and that $T'$ has height $h$.

Now, each node except for the root in a $0$-$2$ tree has exactly one sibling. This means in particular that the nodes we remove from $T$ come in, say, $k$ sibling pairs. For each sibling pair removed, two external nodes are removed and one internal node (the parent) is converted to an external node in $T'$. This gives
$$
n'_e = n_e - 2k + k = n_e - k
$$
and
$$
n'_i = n_i -k.
$$
$T'$ has heigth $h$, so by induction $n'_e = n'_i + 1$, and we get
$$
n_e = n'_e + k = n'_i + 1 + k = n_i + 1.
$$
$\square$